Order bars in an R plotly split bar plot by value
I have measurements from several points to several points in an R data.frame that
I'd like to plot as bars using R's plotly, where each from is split by its tos, and these to's are sorted in ascending order for each from.
Here's the data.frame:
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)
df <- expand.grid(paste0("g", 1:4),paste0("g", 1:6)) %>%
  dplyr::rename(from=Var1, to = Var2) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(dist = runif(24, 0, 1)) %>%
  dplyr::filter(as.character(from) != as.character(to)) %>%
  dplyr::arrange(from,dist)

This plotly command doesn't achieve the sorting of to's that I want:
plotly::plot_ly(x=df$from,y=df$dist,split=df$to,color=df$to,type="bar")


Any idea if there is a way to get the tos sorted for each from?
I tried ggplot2's geom_col with the fct_reorder function from the forcats package, but it neither produces the desired result:
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=forcats::fct_reorder(from,dist),y=dist,fill=to))+geom_col(position='dodge')


Also, ggplot2s facet_grid with setting scales to "free" neither works:
ggplot(df,aes(x=from,y=dist,fill=to))+geom_col(position='dodge')+facet_grid(~from,scales="free",space="free")



This post offers a solution using tidytext::reorder_within and upstartr::scale_x_reordered with geom_bar and facet_wrap:
df %>%
  ggplot() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set2") +
  geom_bar(aes(y = dist, 
               x = tidytext::reorder_within(to, dist, from), 
               fill = to), stat = "identity", show.legend = F) +
  facet_wrap(~ from, scales = "free_x",nrow=1) +
  upstartr::scale_x_reordered() + theme_minimal()+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())


